# No module named settings error django elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a django app to elastic beanstalk. Beanstalk can't find the `settings` file when loading `wsgi.py`. I've seen this in a few other SO questions, but none of those solved my issue.

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kairos_app.prod_settings'
Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/kairos_app/kairos_app/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

These are the contents of the `02_python.config` file under `.ebextensions`:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python3 kairos_app/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python3 kairos_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "kairos_app.prod_settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/kairos_app:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: kairos_app/kairos_app/wsgi.py
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "www/static/"
```

And this is what the directory structure looks like:

[image]

It seems to pick up the WSGIPath okay, so I'm not sure why it can't pick up the django settings module path.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue here. My project structure looks the same as yours and getting ModuleNotFoundError on an app (or apps) in the apis folder. Did you face the same issue there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be looking into the parent `kairos_app` directory.

Try changing

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "kairos_app.prod_settings"
```

into

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "kairos_app.kairos_app.prod_settings"
```

OR

```
"PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/kairos_app:$PYTHONPATH"
```

into

```
"PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/kairos_app/kairos_app:$PYTHONPATH"
```

The latter impacts the whole runtime, so it might break things.

Comment: I had previously tried `kairos_app/kairos_app/prod_settings.py` instead of `kairos_app.kairos_app.prod_settings`. Why wouldn't the first have worked?

Comment: You need to use the address to the module (dot notation) in reference to what is loaded in `PYTHONPATH` -> `/opt/python/current/app/kairos_app` with the root `kairos_app` as base module.